# Docker - use curl in dockerfile

Tags: docker, curl, dockerfile

I want to install node.js in my docker image.

I saw the official installation guide and it mentions curl.

Here is the source:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

How do i use curl in my dockerfile, since it is an external program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend using the [official node image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) if that's what you need.

If that doesn't suit your need, you can simply use cURL by first installing it. There is no such thing as "external program" on a Dockerfile. The Dockerfile does what you tell it to do.

`RUN apt update && apt install curl && curl ....`

Comment: Thank you! I will get ubuntu and curl. Then install node. The reason i don't get the official docker node.js image, is because i also want to have ubuntu. So i jave FROM ubuntu command, then i get the other dependencies. This is the fifth day i try to get both, and this is the last thing i can think of.

Comment: I don;t get the '&& curl ...' part of the command you gave me.

Comment: Actually, i want to be able to run this command:
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
I tried RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash - , but it didn't work.

Comment: What does "have Ubuntu" mean, that you don't get from the `node` image?  The [Docker Hub `node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) has Debian and Alpine variants, and you're probably not going to notice a practical difference between Debian and Ubuntu here.

Comment: @user1584421 the `RUN` statement I added is just running three different commands: `apt update`, `apt install curl` and `curl <whatever-you-want-to-fetch>`. This is basic Linux usage, I'd recommend read a little on this matter before diving into containers.